# Cómo evitar que mi login recargue varias veces cuando doy 2 or 3 +?

Tags: angular

Tengo un login en angular, el cual ya esta finalizado pero cuando le doy al botón varios click me aparece la ventana de logiado las veces que haya dado click, me gustaría que estrategia usan para solucionar esto

ejemplo XD
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta en la informacion que he investigado:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51390476/how-to-prevent-double-click-in-angular

Comment: Mientras la petición esté en proceso deshabilita el botón.

Comment: Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Sin tu código en la pregunta, sólo vas a recibir intentos de adivinación o comentarios. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Answer (score 0):

```
disableLoginButton = false;

login(formUserPassword) {
this.disableLoginButton = true;
return this.http.post(this.config.apiUrl + '/auth/login', 
formUserPassword).pipe(
        subscribe(
            next: (response: any) => {
                this.disableLoginButton = false;
            },
            error: (err) => {
                this.disableLoginButton = false;
            }
        ),
    );
}
```